# ASP.net 3.5 WebMethod Strange Behavior, jQuery AJAX receives strange data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, linq

I've ran into this strange JSON behavior.. I just cant figure out what the hell is going on..

I've got a WebMethod in my asp.net page.. It repetitively calls as page loads through jQuery AJAX.. Everything goes pretty smooth but what strange thing happens is that the data I sens to my jQuery ajax is not the SAME I just sent.. :S

here is not code of page method

```
[WebMethod()]
    public static List<Unister.UnisterCore.Core.Domain.Comment> LoadComments(long objID, int sysID)
    {
        if (objID == 0)
            return null;

        UnisterWeb.UserControls.Presenter.CommentsPresenter _presneter;
        _presneter = new UnisterWeb.UserControls.Presenter.CommentsPresenter();
        List<Unister.UnisterCore.Core.Domain.Comment> comments = new List<Unister.UnisterCore.Core.Domain.Comment>();
        comments = _presneter.LoadComments(sysID, objID);

        if (comments.Count == 0)
            return null;

        return comments;
    }
```

Here returning list is what I got from my presenter layer but when I receive that in my js method, its either null or previous value.

Here is my jQuery method..

```
function LoadComments(SysID, ObjID) {

if (parseInt(SysID) == 0 || parseInt(ObjID) == 0)
    return;

var args = 'objID:' + ObjID + ',sysID:' + SysID;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/dashboard/default.aspx/LoadComments",
    cache: false,
    data: '{' + args + '}',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        if (result.d != null) {
            comments = new Array();

            $.each(result.d, function(key, val) {
                data = new Object();
                data.CommentID = val.CommentID;
                data.Body = val.Body;
                codate = new Date(parseInt(val.CreateDate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
                var fdate = dateFormat(codate, "isoUtcDateTime");
                ldate = $.timeago(fdate);
                data.CreateDate = ldate;
                data.CommentByAccountID = val.CommentByAccountID;
                comments.push(data);
            });

            var boxid = "#commentBox_" + ObjID;
            $(boxid).setTemplateURL("../Templates/comments.htm");
            $(boxid).processTemplate(comments);
        }
    }
});
```

}

Please help me..

Comment: are you calling the web method in a loop

Comment: Im using it in a usercontrol which loads through a repeater.. in short Yes im using in a loop

Comment: try setting `async:false` in the ajax request see if that solves the problem but that is not recommended

Comment: can you tell me thats the problem going on? webmethod is returning a correct list but js is receiving wrong data.

Comment: as you are doing ajax through repeater and ajax is asynchronous before the first request is finished the second req is made and then third and so on may be that is why you are getting data out of sync...

Comment: ahan.. i get it.. maybe i shud use Complete event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution... :)

First thing we could do is make our request async: false (BUT it'll impact our performance).. Instead, Im sending an ID (in my case SysID) and also bind it with my DIV id like the code below..

```
<div id ="comment_<%= SysID %>"></div>
```

In my jQuery function I use

```
var ID = "#comment_" + val.SysteID;
 $(ID).setTemplateURL("../Templates/comments.htm");
 $(ID).processTemplate(comments);
```

Hope it helps you guys too ... :)